# PHP MySQL database from MS Access

Tags: php, mysql, ms-access

I'm developing a php website that is only accessible from a company network. I've been using MySQL to develop my databases, but I need pertinent information that is located in a MS Access database (also located on the network).

The problem is that this MS Access database updates itself every 6 hours - so I will need to:

(1) Make a connection from my php site to the MS Access database located on the network.

(2) Have it periodically update itself.

I have absolutely no clue where to start. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Since the *"MS Access database updates itself every 6 hours"*, adapt the Access db to update MySQL via ODBC links afterward. It's not clear why you should need PHP to mediate the data transfer from Access to MySQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To have it periodically update itself, you may need to have a service do this.  A webpage (running php) will only run when a user goes to that webpage.

Comment: As for connecting to Access look here:  http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_db_odbc.asp